# Understanding ostream overload

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble understanding an error I receive when overloading the ostream method for a class.

Code in class.cpp

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const dateType& d)
{
   out << d.getYear() << "-" << d.getMonth() << "-" << d.getDay()
   return out;
}
```

I know all three getters work, test them in my main.cpp.

However, when I run something like:

```
cout << d1 << endl:
```

I get this error:

```
‘std::ostream& dateType::operator<<(std::ostream&, dateType&)’ must take exactly one argument
 ostream& operator<<(ostream&, dateType&);
```

I wrote an ostream code like this for another program that works fine.  So why do I get the error here?

Comment: You may have declared it as a member. It should be a non-member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote it as a member function of `dateType`, and member `operator<<` may only take one explicit argument (because the first one is implicit and the operator is binary). At the moment you have a sort of three-argument `operator<<`, taking the implicit `dateType`, then `std::ostream&`, then another `dateType`!

Here's how a member `operator<<` would look:

```
struct T
{
   operator<<(ostream&);
};
```

The problem with this is that now you have an `operator<<` that takes `T` on the *left* and the stream on the right, which is reverse to convention. `T() << std::cout` isn't right, is it?

Conventionally, then, we use namespace-scope for our `operator<<` overloads, where we have full control over the parameter order.

That is, **don't make it a member function of `dateType`**.
You may need to make this new function a `friend` of `dateType` if those getters are `private`.

---

> I wrote an ostream code like this for another program that works fine.

No you/it didn't.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't realize I had my ostream code inside the class declaration in my .h file.  I moved both it and my istream declarations outside the class definitions, not the only remaining error I have is:
‘std::istream& dateType::operator>>(std::istream&, dateType&)’ must take exactly one argument
 istream& dateType::operator>>(istream& in, dateType& d)

Am I correct in assuming that this is the same type of problem?

Comment: @Blackwell: Yes. Your `operator>>` is still a member.

Comment: Yep, figured it out just after I posted that.  Thanks very much.

Comment: Ok, one last error to deal with (sorry about all the questions, I was doing fine with c++ up until overloading....).  I'm getting "undefined reference to `operator<<(std::ostream&, dateType&)'" as an error now when I try to link and complile.  I'm not sure I understand the answers I've read.  I'm sure I've defined the function...

Comment: @Blackwell: Please don't treat answer comments as your own personal helpdesk chatroom!

Comment: I apologize.  I'm running on fumes.  Won't happen again.